# Adding a Team Project Collection in TFS2010

Tags: tfs

I’m trying to add a team project collection to a TFS2010 instance.  The instance already has project collections set-up and in use, but when I try to add another I get warnings from the Data Tier Configuration.  The warnings are as follows:

```
TF255153: Service is not set to start automatically: SQL Server Database Services:

TF255437: An error occurred while querying the Windows Management Instrumentation (WMI) interface on the following computer: MYTFSSERVER.  The following error message was received: .

TF255437: An error occurred while querying the Windows Management Instrumentation (WMI) interface on the following computer: MYTFSSERVER.  The following error message was received: .
```

(TF255437 is reported twice)

I’ve had a good look around, and found a couple of articles that implied TF255437 is caused by WMI compatibility not being enabled in IIS (TFS2010 is running on IIS7.5).  However, this is enabled as far as I can tell.

Has anyone come across either of these errors before?  The admin console seems happy for me to create the TPC regardless, but without understanding the errors fully, I’m reluctant to do so.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This was all caused by the "SQL Server Agent" service not being started on the server.